# Multipart/form-data request with multiple files: request seems to be garbled due to odd byte sequence

Tags: java, file-upload, multipartform-data

We need to send a `multipart/form-data` request containing two files. Since we had some issues with the requests, we set up a request bin page to try and analyze the requests themselves, since Postman seemed to work fine.

My second file is generated by a different service as a byte stream and represents a `JSON` object. This byte stream seems to have a `NUL` (0) byte terminator at the end.

If I add this second file to the `multipart/form-data` request, something like the following results:

[image]

With the body looking as follows:

```
--9ac41cec-a0ff-4afd-b687-6b8c2f1bddd6.
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="metadata-1584981615.json".
Content-Type: application/json.
Content-Length: 581.
.
{"...":"..."}.
--9ac41cec-a0ff-4afd-b687-6b8c2f1bddd6.
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file-1584981615.json".
Content-Type: application/json.
Content-Length: 12205.
.
{"...":"..."}..
--9ac41cec-a0ff-4afd-b687-6b8c2f1bddd6--.
```

Obviously, this is supremely invalid. It seems that the `multipart` request is adding the `.` characters at the end of every line.

I was able to reproduce this behaviour with `Spring Web 5.1.5.RELEASE`, `okHttp 3.14.7` and `Apache HttpComponents 4.5.7`. **The behaviour does not seem to change if I remove the `NUL` (0) byte terminator from the byte stream.**

Here's the odd part: the receiving webserver accepts this request as a valid `multipart/form-data` request.

For the record, here's what a valid request (that is also accepted by the webserver) looks like from request bin's point of view (different `file`):

[image]

```
--83611e7f-ad57-4893-9d1b-5ba2c4543d2a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="metadata-1584982345.json"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 895

{"...": "..."}

--83611e7f-ad57-4893-9d1b-5ba2c4543d2a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file-1584982345.json"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 9868

{"...": "..."}
--83611e7f-ad57-4893-9d1b-5ba2c4543d2a--
```

Aside from having the explicit terminator at the end (which does not seem to make a difference at all), the byte stream does not look broken. `new String(bytes)` gives a valid `JSON` object. So I'm thinking it has to be something else.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I'm unsure how to proceed with debugging this issue, and I'm fairly certain that sending improper requests, even though they might be accepted by the remote server at this time, almost certainly guarantees that my code will break somewhere along the line...